# How to transfer player data for a Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am a server owner of a server for my friends and I. My friends recently started using a new account. Is there a way to transfer the data from his old account to the new?

Comment: yes, simply changing the file with his old uuid to his new one

Answer (score 2):

You would find their playerdata file, in the server folder/playerdata, and change their latest file to their new UUID. You could also use a plugin or mod that allows you to access their inventory in game, and you could move the invenotory manually this way.

Answer (score 0):

If your friend's old account is still active then they could put their belongings in a chest and log in to their new account and pick everything up. the only issue with this is the xp levels would still be on their old account.

hope this helped!