# How to transfer savedata from player A to player B on Minecraft Bedrock Server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ubuntu, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I have a Minecraft Bedrock server running on Ubuntu. I just got a new MC account and the old one is no longer accessible. Is there some way to transfer the savedata from my old account to my new one?

[This post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/380511/how-to-transfer-player-data-for-a-minecraft-server) is not a duplicate; its answers are regarding Java edition, not Bedrock.

Comment: https://www.universalminecrafttool.com/

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Hacker I think so, but I'll need to look into it still. Maybe remove your comment and add it as an answer, so if that's the solution you can get the bounty :)

Comment: The Minecraft worlds? That could be doable, but you would need to get the files somehow. Then you could copy it to the server via Linux commands.

Comment: What do you mean by save data?

Answer (score -1):

According to this [thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376577/how-do-i-use-an-nbt-editor-to-modify-item-properties) you should be able to use an NBT editor to see the data on Bedrock edition. According to this [github page](https://github.com/jaquadro/NBTExplorer) an NBT editor is usable as long as you have the mono, and mono windows, framework which is possible to get on Ubuntu.

There are two issues that I foresee, 1 is that you are using a Linux server that you don't have total access to, a potential solution to this would be to transfer your world save to another device, and use a NBT editor locally, and then re-upload it. The 2nd potential issue is that you are not able to copy the NBT data between characters, a solution to this would be to copy down the data somewhere and manually give the items and such to your character using game commands.